# In the definition of critical point, how can $df_p$ be surjective?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $f:M→N$ be a smooth function between two smooth manifolds. Then $p\in M$ is a critical point if $df_p$ is not surjective.

I feel very confused about this definition, even in the case where $M=N=\mathbb{R}$. I can understand at a critical point $p$, $df_p$ sends all tangent vectors at $p$ (all on the x-axis) to a zero tangent vector w.r.t. the y-axis.

But on a regular point, I feel $df_p$ is not surjective either, "since" the tangent direction is fixed at each point $f(p)$. Where does my intuition go wrong?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180232/173147

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're just confused about the meaning of surjective in this case.  In particular, $df_p$ does **not** surject onto $\mathbb{R}^2$: the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}$ is one-dimensional at every point.

For $M = N = \mathbb{R}$, $df_p$ is a linear map from $T_p \mathbb{R} \to T_{f(p)} \mathbb{R}$.  We can identify the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}$ at any point with $\mathbb{R}$ itself, so we can consider $df_p$ as a linear map from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  $df_p$ is given by $df_p(v) = f'(p)v$ where $f'(p)$ is the usual one-variable derivative.  Since its codomain is $1$-dimensional, $df_p$ is either surjective or the zero map, which corresponds exactly to whether $f'(p) = 0$ or $f'(p) \neq 0$.  This follows from the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).  We have
$$
1 = \dim(\mathbb{R}) = \dim(\ker(df_p)) + \dim(\text{img}(df_p))
$$
so either $\dim(\text{img}(df_p)) = 1$ or $\dim(\text{img}(df_p)) = 0$.

Comment: Can I ask the reason why "Since its codomain is 1-dimensional, dfp is either surjective or the zero map"?

Comment: Suppose $df_p=1$. Why is this surjective?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the space spanned by $df_p=1$ is $\mathbb{R}$, but that's not equivalent to $df_p$ being surjective?

Comment: What does $df_p = 1$ mean?  $df_p$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, so it cannot be the constant $1$ map.  If instead you mean that $f'(p) = 1$, so $df_p$ is multiplication by $1$, then $df_p$ is the identity map from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is certainly surjective.

Comment: I think I'm confused about the definition of $df_p$. In my textbook, it seems $df_p$ is the derivative--I'm probably wrong on this, but I have this impression because it can be written as Jacobian matrix.

Comment: Yes!  The derivative is represented by left multiplication by the Jacobian matrix, which is multiplication by the $1 \times 1$ matrix with entry $f'(p)$.

Comment: Can I ask what $v$ means in your formula $df_p(v)=f′(p)v$?

Comment: $df_p$ is a linear map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  It is the line through the origin with slope $f'(p)$, so its equation is $df_p(v) = f'(p) v$ for any $v \in \mathbb{R}$.  It's just the line $y = mx$ with slope $m = f'(p)$.

Comment: Could you take a look at my new question on critical point--http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188815/on-the-definition-of-critical-point

Answer (score 1):

in one dimension we have have a function $f:R\to R$. if $f'(a)\neq 0$ then $df_a (x)=f'(a)x$, i.e., a linear approximation of the function at the point $a$, whose domain is $R$ and codomain $R$. Notice that the image of the function is $R$ as well, therefore $df_a$ is surjective. But when $f'(a)=0$ we have that $df_a(x)=f'(a)\cdot x=0$, so the image is always zero being not equal to the codomain (being $R$). Conclusion: $f'(a)=0$ implies $df_a(x)$ not surjective (and is the only way of $df_a$ to be not surjective).

To prove the opposite, I appeal to the fact that the differential is a linear approximation, and the only way that a straight line not to be surjective is with null slope (because a small inclination projects images in the entire codomain, guaranteeing surjectivity), so to demand not surjectivity to $df_a(x)=f'(a)x$ (which is a straight line) is the same thing that to say $f'(a)=0$.

Final conclusion: Let $f:R\to R$ be a function of $C^\infty$. $a\in R$ is a critical point of $f$ if $df_a(x)$ is not surjective (that is, $f'(a)=0$).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite correct, just that when all tangent vectors at p because it is fixed at each point but since the regular point,dfp wouldn't be surjective due to the point of fixation.

Comment: Sorry that I don't understand your explanation... If at a regular point the differential fails to be surjective, then there'd be something wrong with the definition?!