# On the definition of critical point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth function (or in general between two smooth manifolds). Then $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a critical point if $df_p$ is not surjective. I feel confused about this definition. If $n<m$, then $df_p$ can never be surjective, so that every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is critical in this case?!

For instance, let $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be the curve $\alpha(t)=(\sin t,\cos t)$. Is every $t$ critical?

Comment: Are you suuuuuure that's the definition of critical point?

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @Vladimir I am not sure what is your reference for critical points but this is not the standard definition of critical point. Check wikipedia or any of the standard books (Milnor's : Topology from a differentiable viewpoint is highly recomended).

Comment: Actually Sard's theorem tells you that the set of critical points is of Lebesgue measure zero. So most points of a map are not critical.

Comment: @DBS I think Sard says the set of critical _values_ has measure zero, not necessarily the set of critical points.

Comment: Typically, we define a point to be critical if and only if the pushforward is not *injective*. This coincides with the standard definition of critical point from elementary calculus (i.e. $f'(t)=0\iff t\text{ is a critical point}$).

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow Would you care to cite a source?  John Lee defines critical point exactly as the OP has in his book *Introduction To Smooth Manifolds*, p. 105.  [Wikipedia also agrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28mathematics%29#Critical_point_of_a_differentiable_map) since $F : M \to N$ is a submersion at $p$ iff $dF_p$ is surjective.  Note that OP's definition also agrees with the definition from elementary calculus, since a linear map $T : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is injective iff it is surjective.

Comment: Actually, [here's a better link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_%28mathematics%29) corroborating OP's definition.

Comment: @BenWest Dear Ben yes you are right.

Comment: @SpamIAm -- Oddly, I cannot. It appears that my definition is incorrect. I'm confused as to how that definition got into my head.

Comment: There are two meanings in common use. It depends on if the dimension $n$ or $m$ is larger which is most useful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's the definition! From a manifold of dimension smaller than the target all points are critical, and the regular *values* are the complement of the image. (For instante, the little Sard thm says that complement is residual.)

This may seem not natural in the circle example. There we are dealing with a different matter, that is a *regular* parametrization of the circle: when you consider that circle $S$ as a manifold (a curve), the mapping $\alpha:\mathbb R\to S$ has all points regular.

One main concern of regular points and values is to analyse properly level manifolds (inverses images that are smooth manifolds). The first instance of the notion ofregular point is the Implicit Functions Thm, the far reaching generalization is Thom's crucial notion of Transversality in Differential Topology.

Comment: But can I ask why such a definition is counter-intuitive considering the circle example I give in the question? Why is defining critical point this way beneficial in that case?

Comment: I've edited a bit my answer.