# Confusion about Surfaces, Normal Vectors in $R^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I think I'm having some confusions about some elementary concepts.

I'm studying the book "Calculus of Several Variables" by Lang. I realize the book is not completely rigorous but the following left me questioning some things, while I was trying to understand the author's argument about Lagrange multipliers.

See the screenshots below. The author argues that the gradient vector is the **unique** normal/orthogonal vector at a surface because it's normal to every differentiable curve passing through that surface.

But what if your "surface" was a line in $R^3$ - say the x axis? Then you could have two different orthogonal vectors that are normal to the surface (i.e. y and z axes). But I realize the x-axis can not be put in the form $g(x, y, z) = c$.

So what's going on here? Do points satisfying a constraint such as $g(x, y, z) = c$ always have one **unique** orthogonal vector at every point unlike a line in $R^3$ (in the sense the vector is orthogonal to any curve containing those points)? Can this be proven?

Is a line not a "surface" in $R^3$?

I hope what I'm saying makes sense.

[image: First excerpt from Lang's book]

[image: Second excerpt from Lang's book]

Comment: Is it true that both the $\;y,\,z\;$ axis are orthogonal to **any** curve through the origin and, thus, to the $\;x\;$ axis  there? Because that's what has to be true.

Comment: I don't get your question. Through the x-axis, there's only one curve - namely the x-axis. And the y- and z- axes are orthogonal at every point to this curve.

Comment: I read that part of Lang and I understand now what you meant with the definition of the gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "surface" in this context is defined in the first sentence of your screenshot. It is a result of differential geometry that such a set of points has exactly the $2$-dimensional shape that you have in mind when you hear the word "surface". It cannot be a line.
See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180232/regular-value-intuition-about-surjectivity-condition): in your case, since the target space is $\mathbb{R}$, $\text{grad}\ f(X)$ being non-zero is equivalent to d$_Xf$ being surjective, hence the preimage is locally a $3-1=2$-manifold.

Note also the gradient cannot be uniquely defined by the property you mention. There are infinitely many normal vectors to a surface at a given point (namely all multiples of the gradient).

I am quite surprised by your sentence "I realize the book is not completely rigorous". What do you mean? What is not rigorous?

---

**Edit:** A linear form is what you call a linear transformation in the special case where the codomain has dimension $1$. Say that the domain has dimension $n$. By the rank-nullity theorem, the kernel has to have dimension either $n$ (if the map is trivial) or $n-1$. Note that there is only one direction that is orthogonal to an $n-1$-dimensional subspace - and there is **one** unique orthogonal vector $v_0$ such that your linear form is the inner product $v\mapsto \left< v, v_0\right>$. That vector is nothing but the $1\times n$ matrix that represents the linear map.

In your case, when the linear form is the differential of a smooth function at a given point $p$, and provided that $\operatorname{d}_pf$ is surjective (hence has $n-1$-dimensional kernel), this one unique vector is what you call $\operatorname{grad} f$.

By smoothness, $\operatorname{d}f$ will stay surjective in a neighbourhood of $p$ and the gradient will therefore exist. In such a neighbourhood, $f$ is close to a linear map and its level sets $f^{-1}(c)$ look like $n-1$ dimensional affine subspaces, in the sense that they *are* affine subspaces up to a smooth change of variables.

This is known as the submersion theorem - see for instance [these lecture notes](http://math.mit.edu/~arita/18.101/manifolds-1.pdf), Theorem 1.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Regarding the book's rigor, Lang himself says the book is not too concerned with theory - it wasn't meant as a slight.

As far as vectors go, I meant that vectors that are scalar multiples of each other are equivalent.

Can you prove or provide a reference for the claim that grad f is the only unique normal vector for every point (in the sense of being orthogonal to every curve) for a surface of the form $f(\vec x) = c$?

The question you link to is above my level. If you feel the answer requires significant diff geo, I may pass.

Comment: And as far as rigor goes, I don't think the author answers this question - but again I suspect the answer may take us too far afield.

Comment: @AnlamK Here is rough explanation: by definition the gradient is the vector that represents the linear form $df$ at a given point. Along a curve lying in $f^{-1}(c)$, $f(\gamma(t))$ is constant and its derivative is $0$, therefore the tangent vector of such a curve at the given point is orthogonal to the gradient.

Comment: Yes, the fact that any curve going through the surface is orthogonal to the grad follows easily from the chain rule; as you point out. 

My question is whether grad is the only *unique* such vector (ignoring scalar multiples) and why. Your original answer has some clues as to why but it's opaque to me.

Comment: Thanks - if you can explain what a linear form is, what a kernel of a liinear form is (kernel for me only means null space of a linear transformation), why it has dim n-1 and expand on your answer and/or perhaps point to some additional references (is this the domain of differential geometry?), I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @AnlamK edited, I hope it makes sense.